# is it possible to write an extension method only for List<T> where T is a class that inherits from class K

Tags: c#, inheritance, extension-methods

Lets say I have a Base Class:

```
public class Base{

}
```

I have a class Derived that inherits from Base Class:

```
public class Derived: Base{

}
```

Is it possible to write an extension method, for a `List<T>` of classes, that inherit only from the Base class, something like this:

```
public static string F(this List<Base> baseClass){
    return "This class inherits from Base Class";
}
```

The extension method should work for `List<Base>` and `List<Derived>`. But it doesn't for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public static string F<T>(this List<T> baseClass)
  where T : Base
{
    return "This class inherits from Base Class";
}
```

The method must be generic because `List<Derived>` is not a subtype of `List<Base>` (and not a supertype either).

If `IEnumerable` is enough for you *and* this was an interface or delegate method I think you could solve this with covariance, too.